# Axis2 service.xml description

Tags: deployment, apache-axis

Is there a description of all the possible elements of the service.xml file, an XSD file or the list of all s available?

Comment: http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/axis2config.html#Service_Configuration

Comment: what about possible `<parameter>` types?

Comment: Parameters are generic configuration elements. The documentation states that the "ServiceClass" parameter is compulsory. Why? Well if you dig into the javadocs you'll discover that the message receiver enabled expects this parameter to be set: http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/receivers/RawXMLINOutMessageReceiver.html.  Axis2 is very configurable. It's possible for your application to access parameters defined in the services.xml file. Useful feature if you need it.